# Cannot find the user '', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am trying to add permissions to a Store procedure for a user using this query,

```
USE [MyDatabaseName]
GO

GRANT EXEC ON [dbo].[StoreProcedureName] TO [UserName]
GO
```

**I can give permissions to user through theUser Interface** but using this query I get this error,

> Cannot find the user 'UserName', because it does not exist or you do not have
>   permission.

If I don't have permissions then how can I add permissions using User Interface.

Comment: Are you sure the UserName exists? If it's a windows account prepend the domain name too.

Comment: I made it up and yeah my user with that name does exists..

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory - are you connected as a sysadmin or dbo? Either the username is incorrect, or you don't have adequate permissions.

Comment: I am running query in SQL Server management studio and if I don't have permissions then how can I add it throw UI ??

Comment: Have you tried putting the actual user name after `TO` in single quotes?  Such as: `GRANT EXEC ON [dbo].[StoreProcedureName] TO 'sa'`

Comment: thats incorrect syntax mate

Comment: What does the query `select * from sys.database_principals where name = 'UserName'` return? And is your server using a case-sensitive collation?

Comment: it returns the user @Pondlife

Comment: Then it looks like permissions, what do `select is_rolemember('db_owner')` and `select is_srvrolemember('sysadmin')` return?

Comment: both returns No column name as  1

Comment: So the user exists and you have admin rights. That leaves case sensitivity or a more basic issue like being connected to the wrong server and/or database. Have you checked those points? And since you said that you can do this through the GUI, what happens if you use the Script button? Is there any difference between the script it generates and the script you've written?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I just encountered the same problem.

Make sure there is a user mapping for your login in the master table. No database role memberships are required, just tick 'Map' for the database master under 'User Mapping' in the properties for the login 'UserName'.

Answer (score 26):

Run this:

```
USE [db_where_you_need_access]
GO
CREATE USER [your_user] FOR LOGIN [your_user]
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue and yet I am in the local admin group on the server. Apparently if UAC is turned onrunning SQL Server Management Studio as administrator makes a world of difference. I didn't have any permissions until I did this.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. For clarity: The solution for me was to right click the SQL Server Management Studio icon on my desktop and select "Run as administrator" from the context menu. Then I was able to your `GRANT EXECUTE...` without issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get problems like this when a database has been restored from another server and the GUID of the user in the database is different from that of the current server.

This will re-link orphaned users:

```
USE <database_name>;
GO
sp_change_users_login @Action='update_one', @UserNamePattern='<database_user>', 
   @LoginName='<login_name>';
GO
```

other than this, if the user exists and you have the relevant security rights, there is no reason what you doing wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a daft one, but make sure your `UserName` is spelt correctly in the `GRANT` statement.  I spent half an hour trying to figure out what the cause of this error was and it was simply a typo on my part!