# Getting the following error in SQL Server 2012 "Cannot find the user '<user>', because it does not exist or you do not have permission"

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am not able to grant execute permissions. I'm essentially having the same problem as this question but I didn't see any solutions that work in my situation.

[Cannot find the user '', because it does not exist or you do not have permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040557/cannot-find-the-user-because-it-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-have-permission)

I am trying to run the following command:

```
use master 
go

grant exec on sp_OACreate to [db_user]
GO
```

I am a sysadmin on this box and the user does exist. This is a SQL Server login as opposed to a Windows login.

Interestingly, when I run the below statement it comes back empty.

```
select * from sys.database_principals where name = 'db_user'
```

I'm sure this has something to do with it but I can't figure out how to get this user into the `database_principals` table. This particular database was restored from a vendor's staging environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This user needed to be added to the master database.  Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe it was an orphaned user because it had a login but no user account in the master db.  I've run the below command to add the user to the master db.

```
USE master
GO

CREATE USER db_user FOR LOGIN db_user
GO
```

I was then able to add the execute permissions to this user.