# granting Sp_helptext not working

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Whenever I run

```
Grant Execute on sp_helptext to USER
```

I get an error :

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot find the USER, because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I am logged in as `SA` using `master`, so I tried using testing DB and it tells me to use `master`.

How do I create a server login, corresponding to two databases that have the ability to `SELECT` and do `SP_Helptext`. I am able to to do it in production DB just fine but whenever I restore to TESTING nothing I've tried works.

Comment: You did not mention if the user [USER] exists in the database you're having problems with. And if it does, note that USER is a [reserved keyword in T-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) so you should escape it with square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is perfect, but this shows that your user is not mapped with master table. What is your username to grant, Is it "USER"? change with other user to test.

> By default users were able to see object definitions in SQL Server
>   2000, but in SQL Server 2005 this functionality was removed to allow
>   another layer of security.  By using a new feature called VIEW
>   DEFINITION it is possible to allow users that only have public access
>   the ability to see object definitions.
>
> To turn on this feature across the board for all databases and all
>   users you can issue the following statement:

```
USE master 
GO 
GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO PUBLIC (refer the last link)
```

Check this link.

[Cannot find the user '', because it does not exist or you do not have permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040557/cannot-find-the-user-because-it-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-have-permission)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29969/cant-grant-role-permissions-under-sysadmin-login

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1593/granting-view-definition-permission-to-a-user-or-role-in-sql-server/